# How to add warning beep in perl

Tags: perl

I have looked up the following link:

http://search.cpan.org/~giulienk/Audio-Beep-0.11/Beep.pod

and I tried the following code:

```
use Audio::Beep;
$freq=440;
$milliseconds=100;
beep($freq, $milliseconds);

use Audio::Beep;
my $beeper = Audio::Beep->new();

my $music = "g' f bes' c8 f d4 c8 f d4 bes c g f2";
$beeper->play( $music );
```

but this gives the following error:

Couldn't find a working player at C:\wamp\www\beep.pl line 5

Comment: although print"\a"; works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate player module for your system?  See the modules listed here: http://search.cpan.org/~giulienk/Audio-Beep-0.11/.  You need one of the submodules (such as `Audio::Beep::Linux::PP`, etc.) to use this.  Also, the documentation for `Audio::Beep` shows how to specify the player you want to use: http://search.cpan.org/~giulienk/Audio-Beep-0.11/Beep.pod#OO_Methods

Comment: @dan1111: The player modules are part of `Audio-Beep` and are unlikely to be omitted if the core module is there.

Comment: @SanchitTyagi: Which Windows system are you using?

Comment: @Borodin Im using windows.

Comment: @SanchitTyagi: *Which Windows system are you using?*

Comment: @Borodin Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 SP 3

Comment: It's unlikely to be the problem, but have you checked that you have `Win32::API` installed? And do you have a sound card and speakers?

Answer (score 5):

Like the ASCII bell?

```
my $bell = chr(7);
print $bell;
```

May not work, depending on the nature of your terminal.

Comment: it didn't work for me but print "\a"; worked. oh I guess on debug window I can't do "my $bell= ". should be "$bell="

Comment: this plays the default Windows sound on Windows which is good

Comment: As mentioned before, this is just another version of `print "\a";`, see also [Bell character - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character "Bell character - Wikipedia").

Answer (score 4):

You've misread the `Perldoc`.

You do either:

```
use Audio::Beep;
beep ($freq, $milliseconds);
```

OR

```
use Audio::Beep;
my $beeper = Audio::Beep->new;
my $music = "g' f bes' c8 f d4 c8 f d4 bes c g f2";
$beeper->play ($music);
```

Also look at the [Requirements](http://search.cpan.org/~giulienk/Audio-Beep-0.11/Beep.pod#REQUIREMENTS) section of the Perldoc. You might not have all the pieces you need for it. Interesting, the copyright is 2004, but has no support for Windows 95, ME, 98, or XP -- all of the Windows operating systems that had been out for the previous decade since the copyright. In other words, this might not do Windows at all.

Comment: I think *you* have misread the POD. It says that it requires Windows NT, 2000, or XP, and excludes 95, 98 and ME. The OP,says he is on XP so no problem there. And there is no reason to suspect that *both* forms of call can't coexist in the same programming.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I use

```
use Win32::Sound;
Win32::Sound::Play("SystemDefault");
```

https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Sound